# Ratios to get the total

Tags: ratio

How do you solve this question?

> A cookie jar contains only two types of cookies - macaroons and
>   ginger snaps. The ratio of macaroons to ginger snaps is $2:5$. Which of
>   the following could be the total number of cookies in the cookie jar?

```
[X] 42
[ ] 45
[ ] 48
[ ] 52
[ ] 57
```

Why is the answer $42$?

Comment: It's the only option that is divisible by $2+5=7$, since the question assumes that we can't break the cookies into halves or fifths and so on.

Comment: "Why is the answer 42?" Yes, this confused the Magratheans too.

Comment: For those of us needing a refresher on the Magratheans and the number 42: http://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Magrathean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is the only multiple of $7=2+5$: $2$ parts of macaroons and $5$ parts of gingers.

The total number of biscuits must be $2n+5n=7n$, with $n$ integer, and $42$ is the only multiple of $7$ in your list.